# Verifying Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

I am reading Mathematical Statistics for Economics and Business by Mittelhammer  he stated on page 59 that this function $$ f(x)=(0.3)^x(0.7)^{1-x}I_{[0,1]}(x)$$ could serve as discrete probability density function .

My qustion is , how this function could be a discrete probability density function  when $$f(x)\neq 0   \forall x  \neq  {0, 1} ?$$

Comment: $x$ takes only two values - $0$ and $1$ with probabilities $0.7$ and $0.3$ respectively.

Comment: @A.S.yes , the countable set conatins just $0$ and $1$

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor, $I[\{0,1\}](x)$ , is an indicator function; a piecewise function having the value of $1$ when $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $0$ elsewhere.  This is what ensures that $f(x)$ is zero elsewhere.

$$I[\{0,1\}](x) = \begin{cases}1 & : x= 0\vee x=1 \\ 0 & : \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok  ,But  why I have to check this condition $$f(x)= 0   \forall x  \neq  {0, 1} ?$$ in order to know if a function could be a discrete probability density function ? I mean this condition is always in advance  verified

Comment: A random variable is discrete if the support consists of a countable set of discrete points.  It need not necessarily be $\{0,1\}$ specifically, but that is an example of such a set.

Comment: PS: In addition, @BahgatNassour , you also need to verify that $sum_{x\in\{0,1\}} f(x) = 1$, and that $\forall x\in\{0, 1\}\; f(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: I also need to verify that the sum equals to one , or I need just to verify that the sum equals to one ?That is the essence of my question

Comment: Oh I got it  :), May be I have to sleep  .thanks